# Where are my local webserver pages?

Tags: webserver

My webserver is running -

[image]

Where is this page coming from?  I checked a few places in /etc and /var but didn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is index.html and is located in

```
/var/www/index.html
```